# How to set a privileges on Table/Schema in oracle

Tags: oracle, private

How to set Privilege on particular table and On Schema in Oracle Database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to grant the privilege, Refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.6.1.0/ref/rrefsqljgrant.html) for more about granting privileges in oracle.

If you need to grant `SELECT` on table to a user, try:

```
GRANT SELECT ON <table_name> TO <user_name>;
```

Comment: how to create user user_name?

Comment: @chocolate, User_name is same as your schema_name. You can grant on a particular schema_name.

Comment: @Dbafirst of all tell me how to create privilege?

Comment: @chocolate, You don't need to create a privilege. You just grant it for a user.

Comment: I given GRANT SELECT ON account_mapping TO system but am not accessing account_mapping in system schema.why?let me know whats the wrong

Comment: You don't need to grant any privilege to user system, because system is a superuser, it already have all the privileges granted at the time of user creation. If you want to access the table from system user, just try like: `select * from <schema_name>.account_mapping;`.

Comment: `select * from system.account_mapping`; getting error `SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:`

Comment: `<schema_name>` is the name which your table `account_mapping` is present. For example, if you want to query the table `emp` in `scott` user, from system you should query like: `select * from scott.emp;`

Comment: ya working.But i have one doubt.can you clarify that please